# Landscape Picture + Table format

Tags: tables, graphics, memoir, landscape

I'm using `latex`, and `memoir`, and I want to create a page template that would always take one and only one page, containing a picture that is aligned to the left of the page, and always fitted inside a predefined boundary, and a table with a fixed number of cells (or any combination of rows and columns) and fixed boundaries which is aligned to the right of the page.

This will be in landscape, while the document itself (header and footer...etc.) will be in portrait orientation. Also, I would like it be always facing on direction (towards binding in verso, and towards margin in recto) regardless of which page it is on (I'm using a `twopage` option for `memoir`).

It should look something like this:

[image: Landscape image/table template]

My tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\copypagestyle{ruledsmallhd}{ruled}
\makeevenhead{ruledsmallhd}{\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{ruledsmallhd}{}{}{\footnotesize\scshape\rightmark}
\makeheadrule{ruledsmallhd}{0px}{0px}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{ruledsmallhd}   
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{Image1}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
ColumnA&ColumnB&ColumnC\\ \hline
1&2&3\\
A&B&C\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{./Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Removed unnecessary lines and added the image and table environments.

Comment: Headers and bibliography are not necessary either, just use `\pagestyle{ruled} to show where they are. The `rotating` (AFAIR) package seem to be the package you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, have a look at [the `rotating` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating) and its `sidewaysfigure`/`sidewaystable` commands. Combined with [the `subcaption` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) you should be able to build something like what you're asking for.

For example this:
[image]
was produced by:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{ruled}   
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{image}\label{img_left}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subtable}{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
            ColumnA&ColumnB&ColumnC\\ \hline
            1&2&3\\
            A&B&C\\
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{table}\label{tbl_right}
        \end{subtable}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```